# Refer to "this" subclass instead of "this" superclass in Java?

Tags: java, oop, this

I have constructed a superclass and a batch of subclasses for one of my current Java projects - in this case, I want to define a function in the superclass, to be inherited by all subclasses. This function will use "this" in order to refer to the attributes in the subclasses, but this currently refers to the attributes in the SUPERclasses instead.

F.e., I have created a superclass and a subclass, where both classes have the attribute "value". A function is used to print out the value, where "this" is supposed to refer to the current class.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child myObject = new Child();
        myObject.printValue();
    }
}

class Parent{
    private int value = 10;
    public void printValue(){
        System.out.println(this.value);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    private int value = 20;
}
```

In this case, I want to target the value in the subclass (20), by using "this" to refer to the current class. But, "this" currently refers to the "value" in the SUPERclass, resulting in the same printed message for all subclasses.

Can I set "this" to refer to the class where the function is used?

Comment: I think the use of interfaces and abstract classes/methods may be more in line with what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have tried to switch to interfaces but I will need superclasses instead. My problem now is that I must implement the function in EACH subclass to reach "this" for each class, which feels inefficient. Is there really no easy way to just set "this" to refer to the class calling the function?

Comment: Do the subclasses need a field that's different from the parent class? Could they just use the parent's field?

Comment: Yes, the attributes will be unique for each class.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because fields cannot be "overridden" in subclasses. Only methods can be overridden.

You can get the effect you want if you create a `getValue` method replace `this.value` with a call to `getValue`.

```
class Parent{
    private int value = 10;
    public void printValue(){
        System.out.println(getValue());
    }
    protected int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    private int value = 20;

    @Override
    protected int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This leads to the same scenario that OP was trying to avoid where they have to put an identical method in every subclass (the getValue() method)

Comment: This is how field resolution works in Java. Any other solution will require a lot more creativity,

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my current problem since I define the methods in EACH subclass, which feels extremely ineffecient.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is that "don't try to override fields of superclass" because java doesn't support that. If you have a field "value" in subclass, then discard it and use the field from superclass instead. Create a setter method in superclass to set the value or use constructor. The following code will work:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child myObject = new Child();
        myObject.setValue(20);      // whatever value you want 
        myObject.printValue();
    }
}

class Parent{
    private Integer value = 10;
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void printValue(){
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{

}
```

If you absolutely must have a separate field "value" in subclass, honestly i think the class design is wrong. You should name the field differently (e.g "value2") because java will treat it as a different field from the one with same name in superclass. Design your code to have a childObject.setValue(value2) somewhere before calling printValue()

Answer (score 0):

We will use key word ***this*** to access current class and use key word ***super*** to access superclass. We can not access subclasses in the superclass because it does not have privilege . The idea behind inheritance in Java is that you can create new classes that are built upon existing classes and have their unique properties, which are different from their parents. If you want to access superclass properties ,you need to write method in subclasses to access. If you still want to access subclass properties in superclass ,why do you make subclasses extend superclass.

```
public class Main{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            Child myObject = new Child();
            myObject.printValue();
            myObject.printSuperValue();
        }
}

    class Parent{
        private int value = 10;
        public void printValue(){
            System.out.println(this.value);
        }
    }

    class Child extends Parent{
        private int value = 20;


        @Override
        public void printValue(){
            System.out.println(this.value);
        }

        public void printSuperValue(){
            super.printValue();
        }
    }
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly my solution today, which feels bad since I need a LOT OF values in each subclass, and therefore have to declare a batch of methods for each class, which makes the code pretty extensive.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is that, using simple variable access, there is no way to have the variable resolve dynamically relative to the concrete type of the instance which is being accessed.  What variable will be resolved is based on the declared type of the instance which is being accessed.  For example:

```
public class SampleGrandparent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new SampleChild(0)).printMe();
    }

    public int value;

    public SampleGrandparent(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static class SampleParent extends SampleGrandparent {
        @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
        public int value;

        public SampleParent(int value) {
            super(value + 1);

            this.value = value;
        }

    }

    public static class SampleChild extends SampleParent {
        @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
        public int value;

        public SampleChild(int value) {
            super(value + 1);

            this.value = value;
        }

        public void printMe() {
            System.out.println("Child Value [ " + value + " ]");
            System.out.println("Parent Value [ " + ((SampleParent) this).value + " ]");
            System.out.println("Grandparent Value [ " + ((SampleGrandparent) this).value + " ]");
        }
    }
}
```

For dynamic resolution, methods will need to be used.

You can partially get around this, but only if the variables and subclass names are all known to the superclass.  For example:

```
public class SampleGrandparent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleGrandparent gp = new SampleParent(0);
        gp.printMe();
    }

    public int value;

    public SampleGrandparent(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void printMe() {
        if ( this instanceof SampleChild ) {
            System.out.println("Child Value [ " + ((SampleChild) this).value + " ]");
        }
        if ( this instanceof SampleParent) {
            System.out.println("Parent Value [ " + ((SampleParent) this).value + " ]");
        }
        System.out.println("Grandparent Value [ " + value + " ]");
    }

    public static class SampleParent extends SampleGrandparent {
        @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
        public int value;

        public SampleParent(int value) {
            super(value + 1);

            this.value = value;
        }

    }

    public static class SampleChild extends SampleParent {
        @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
        public int value;

        public SampleChild(int value) {
            super(value + 1);

            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

A getter could be written in the superclass which does the same as 'printMe'.

This is all getting quite ugly, and is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you can entertain is using reflection to access the fields of the current class. The `getClass` method returns the actual class of the object, so for an object of the Child class it will return the Child class, even if the code is in the Parent class. You can access fields declared by that class using the `getDeclaredField()` method.

```
class Parent{
    private int value = 10;

    private int getValueWithReflection() {
        try {
            Field valueField = getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
            valueField.setAccessible(true);
            return valueField.getInt(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void printValue(){
        System.out.println(getValueWithReflection());
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    private int value = 20;
}
```